# Pass 2D array to another Activity

Tags: android, multidimensional-array, parcelable

how do i pass 2 denominational array object as a parameter to another activity

how to get two dimensional array string value in another activity

```
   String [][]str;

    Intent l = new Intent(context,AgAppMenu.class);
                 l.putExtra("msg",str);
                 l.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);   
                 context.startActivity(l);



  another Activity class

   String[][] xmlRespone2;

    xmlRespone2 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("msg");
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use [putSerializable.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putSerializable%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable%29) Arrays are serializable.

To store:

`bundle.putSerializable("list", selected_list);`  // Here bundle is Bundle object.

To access:

```
String[][] passedString_list = (String[][]) bundle.getSerializable("list");
```

### Example

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
mBundle.putSerializable("list", selected_list);
mIntent.putExtras(mBundle);
```

Comment: when i access this object in diffent classs bunvle makes error

Comment: public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  
 
  
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.agappmenu);

  mno = getIntent().getExtras().getString("mno");
  pinno = getIntent().getExtras().getString("pinno");
  
  
  
  String[][] xmlRespone2 = (String[][]) bundle.getSerializable("msg");

Comment: bundle not resolve in another activity where i access this value

Comment: Try this . Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
(String[][]) bundle.getSerializable("msg");

Comment: @ChiragRaval Hi, I tried doing your steps, but when I got to `resultMatrix = (double[][]) bundle.getSerializable("resultMatrix_");`, I got the exception `java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to double[][]`.

Answer (score 6):

This finally works well for me :

To start a new activity (sending String[][] and String):

```
String[][] arrayToSend=new String[3][30];
String stringToSend="Hello";
Intent i = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);

i.putExtra("key_string",stringToSend);

Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
mBundle.putSerializable("key_array_array",  arrayToSend);
i.putExtras(mBundle);

startActivity(i);
```

To access in NewActivity.onCreate:

```
String sReceived=getIntent().getExtras().getString("key_string");

String[][] arrayReceived=null;
Object[] objectArray = (Object[]) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("key_array_array");
if(objectArray!=null){
    arrayReceived = new String[objectArray.length][];
    for(int i=0;i<objectArray.length;i++){
        arrayReceived[i]=(String[]) objectArray[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may define a custom class which implements `Parcelable` and contains logic to read and write 2-dimensional-array from/to Parcel. Afterwards, put that parcelable object inside `Bundle` for transportation.

Answer (score 0):

set the 2darray as public static void. 
let current_class be the class in which we create our 2d array
We want to pass the data to NewActivity

```
Class<?> ourClass=Class.forName("com.example.testapp.NewActivity");
Intent ourIntent= new Intent(current_class.this,ourClass);
intent_name.putExtra("name", 2darray_name);
startActivity(ourIntent);`
```

to access this in NewActivity , use current_class.2darray_name where current_class is the class where it was originally defined.

Answer (score -1):

one Solution is that you can set it as Static so that you can use that in any of your activity.

```
Class A{
 public static String [][]str;
...
    Intent l = new Intent(context,AgAppMenu.class);
                 l.putExtra("msg",str);
                 l.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);   
                 context.startActivity(l);


}

Class B{

...
you can use it with Just A.(ArrayName)
System.out.println(A.str);

}
```

Hope it will Help you.