# ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.String[][]

Tags: java, android, arrays, casting, arraylist

I'm having a problem with Android when passing a 2d array to another activity. I have no problems sending it through a extra as a serializable. But when receiving it, i get the following error:

E/AndroidRuntime(7396): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.String[][]

I'm using the following code:

```
public void getMatriz(){
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    if(extras!=null){
        String[][] matriz = (String[][]) extras.getSerializable("matriz");

    }

}
```

Can someone help me solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the 2d string array you pass very large?

Comment: I think the exception is self-explanatory. You can't cast an array of array to an array. You need to do manual conversion.

Comment: @ArunAntony No, it is not very large.

Comment: @RohitJain I don't understand. It is not an array of arrays, it's a 2d array. I did this following examples I found in StackOverflow.

Comment: @user2588434. Yes, they are the same thing.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214847/pass-2d-array-to-another-activity this should work.  Just to confirm, you're setting the extra with `setSerializable`?

Comment: @RohitJain how do you suggest i Do manual conversion?

Comment: @fadden Yes, I used that example but I get this error. I set the extra with setSerializable just like that post says.

Answer (score 0):

You need to deserialize to get back stream array.

For e.g. following code snippet you can pass serializable as `ObjectInputStream`.

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
return (String[][]) ois.readObject();
```

Comment: Thanks Minitech for useful changes :)