# How to pass 2 dimensional array to broadcast receiver class

Tags: android, arrays, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I am new in Android and facing problem in passing intent my main activity class is passing intent to the class which implements broadcast receiver and intent contains 2 dimensional array

//here curDts is my  2-dimensional array

```
Bundle b=new Bundle();
        b.putSerializable("dates", curDts );
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtras(b);

public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    Bundle b = arg1.getExtras();
    //Log.v("hahahha","curDts");
        String[][] my_date = (String[][])b.getSerializable("dates");
        Log.v("dates",my_date+"--");
    }
```

**here my_date is showing null**

Comment: try this ..http://stackoverflow.com/a/12214949/1265724

Comment: if you chk my code  i am doing the same thing

Comment: Actually you need to parcelize the data which you are sending. Here you implement this by using arraylist and class with two variables.

Answer (score 0):

like this. but i never compile and run it.

```
Bundle b=new Bundle();   
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);         
intent.putExtra("len", curDts.length);
    for(int i = 0; i < curDts.length; i++){
       intent.putExtra("item" + i, curDts[i]);
    }

public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
//Log.v("hahahha","curDts");
    String[][] my_date = new String[][arg1.getIntExtra("len")];
    for(int i = 0; i < arg1.getIntExtra("len"); i++){
         my_date[i] = arg1.getStringArrayExtra("item"+i, null);
    }
    Log.v("dates",my_date+"--");
}
```