# Passing 2D array of objects to another Activity

Tags: android

I'm trying to pass array of (objects) unfortunately (as far as i know) serializable bundle will not work with custom objects.

I have class seat:

```
   public class seat{
    boolean state;
    int Seatb;
    }
```

And here is a code from the first activity:

```
seat [][] arrseat=new seat[20][20];
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
intent.putExtra("data", arrseat);
startActivity(intent);
```

Second activity:

```
seat [][] obseat=new seat[20][20];
Intent intent = getIntent();
obseat=intent.?
```

I could not find a way to get the array from intent

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214847/pass-2d-array-to-another-activity

Comment: This question might be related? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2141166/4194289

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are serializable, So you can use putSerializable.
to put value

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, AnotherClass.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putSerializable("arr", seat);
i.putExtras(b);
```

to get value

```
seat[][] arrseat = (seat[][]) bundle.getSerializable("arr");
```

[also it is a similar problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214847/pass-2d-array-to-another-activity)

Comment: b.putSerializable("arr", seat); don't works with array of objects

Comment: @kalebora the reason why it doesn't work is because `seat` needs to implement `Serializable` interface